Prove that $BE^{\alpha}$ is a Banach Space
Let $E$ a Banach space, can we prove that the set
$$BE^{\alpha}=\{f \in S': \ \sup_{t>0}t^{\alpha}\|G(t)f\|_{E} < +\infty\}$$
is also a Banach space? Here $S'$ is the set of tempered distributions $S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\alpha>0$ and $G(t)$ is the heat semigroup, that is, $G(t)(\cdot)=(4\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}*(\cdot)$.
I am trying to prove that all absolutely convergent series is convergent, but I don't know if I can use the fact that $S'$ is a Banach space.

$S'$ is not a Banach space as it is not even normable. Did you mean to say Fréchet space instead?

Do you know more about $E$, or is it just a Banach space which is seemingly (algebraically) contained in $S'$ and in which $G(t)(f)$ belongs to $E$ for all $t$ and all the involved $f$?

@BrunoB I know that for every $t>0$, $G(t):E \to E$  is continuous, but I don't know if it help us.
